# Best aws rds machine instance for specified ETL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I would like to choose a pg rds for an ETL that I am working on. The concept is that I want to load every 4h and once a week csv files from s3 to postgres. I have around 10 parallel loads of files varying from KB to GB. As it is now with a `t3.small` the load for a partitioned folder of 30GB takes more than 20h (and most of the times tested it completely failed) while smaller folders of 1GB can take up to 2h.

I am working on optimising the load from data engineering perspective, like avoiding deletes, creating indexes after loading etc.
Also I am experimenting with updating some parameters as suggested in the official [doc](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/optimized-bulk-loading-in-amazon-rds-for-postgresql/).

Still I am certain that this machine definitely doesn't work. Can someone please suggest the bare minimum machine that I should have for my case? Note that I don't have a large volume of data, every 4h I want to copy up to approximately 7GB of data and once a week 50GB of data.

[image: AAS]

Execution plan for one of the copies from s3 to pg. 1GB file:

```
Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=1225272.639..1225272.650 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=48984552 read=82716 dirtied=1087394 written=1618757
  I/O Timings: read=725497.871 write=11315.914
Planning Time: 0.031 ms
Execution Time: 1225449.639 ms
```

I am not sure how to interpret the values though as it's not a typical query plan to focus on which parts take longer

Comment: 30GB in 20 hours, that's a mere 434kB per second. Why is your ETL proces so slow? Any RDS instance should be able to proces data much faster. Where is all the time spent?

Comment: @FrankHeikens that is what also doesn't make sense to me, I have provided the AAS pic above. My ETL is pretty standard for some tables I drop and recreate them and then copy the data from s3, and for others I create an stg copy from s3 and then insert with update on conflict. So I assume it's the machine at fault here for the lag

Comment: These machines can handle dozens of MB's per second, you're not even close. Your "standard ETL" is most likely the culprit, but we have no idea of your definition of "standard". A "drop table" could wait for hours when someone is using that table, because of the lock. We can't see that, you can.

Comment: No locks, for now I am the only one writing/reading in this machine. Indicatively I have a table, let's call it `test` with primary key on `id` and index on `colA`. When I try a drop, recreate and `aws_s3.table_import_from_s3` on a file of 1GB this takes more than 1h. Now I am not sure of what other processes are running on the machine (like autovacuums) but still it doensn't make sense to take that long